# In Ruby, can I give access to a protected method to a different specified class?

Tags: ruby, private

For example, I'd like to do something like this

```
class Child
  @name = "Bastion, please, call my name!"
  attr_reader :name
end

class Parent
  @name = "I am a parent"
  def rename_child(child,name)
    child.name = name
  end
end

bastion = Parent.new()
princess = Child.new()

bastion.rename_child(princess,"Moon Child")
```

I only want instances of the `Parent` class to be able to change the `@name` of a `Child` class.

**EDIT**

I only want instances of the `Parent` class to be able to change the `@name` of a `Child` *instance*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant for `@name` to be an instance variable, rather than a class instance one...if my hunch is right, you can do this using `#send`:

```
class Child
  def initialize
    @name = "Bastion, please, call my name!"
  end
  attr_reader :name
  private
  attr_writer :name
end

class Parent
  def initialize
    @name = "I am a parent"
  end
  def rename_child(child, name)
    child.send(:name=, name)
  end
end

bastion, princess = Parent.new, Child.new

p princess.name
#=> "Bastion, please, call my name!"

bastion.rename_child(princess, "Moon Child")

p princess.name
#=> "Moon Child"
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that. The problem is not the method being private. You cannot access a class instance variable by an accessor defined on an instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible. The closest you can get is:

```
class Child
  @name = "Bastion, please, call my name!"
  attr_reader :name
end

class Parent
  @name = "I am a parent"
  def rename_child(child,name)
    child.instance_variable_set(:@name, name)
  end
end
```

Note that `instance_variable_set` is a public method, which together with `eval` makes private/public differences in ruby not to be so strict as in other languages. Those methods should be use extremely cautiously and they are usually considered to be slightly 'hacky'.